# como llamar a los subreportes de un reporte maestro java servlet

Tags: jsp, ireport, jasper

He logrado generar un reporte con exito el cual no tiene `subreportes`.

Pero al momento de mostrar un reporte con varios subreportes no he generar el reporte

Este es mi `servlet controller`

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ActividadM/reporteActividadesM.jasper");
            byte[] fichero = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(in, parameters, conexion);             
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=ReportesSubcomponetes.pdf");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            response.setContentLength(fichero.length);
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(fichero, 0, fichero.length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Log de la consola

> 25-Sep-2018 15:22:32.061 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-244] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke El Servlet.service() para el servlet [ReporteController] en el contexto con ruta [/sisfinop] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con causa raíz
>    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:814)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:377)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:401)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.createEvaluator(JRFillSubreport.java:494)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReportEvaluator(JRFillSubreport.java:477)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:444)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:326)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:455)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2024)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:754)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:124)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:540)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:393)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:89)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:457)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:418)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:297)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:780)
>       at org.pmgm.com.controller.ReporteController.processRequest(ReporteController.java:171)
>       at org.pmgm.com.controller.ReporteController.doPost(ReporteController.java:226)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: que error te esta dando en la consola?

Comment: o debo darle la ruta de los subreportes?

Comment: Si tienes que poner la ruta como parametro o dentro del reporte

Comment: le di como parametro la ruta de la carpeta de los subreportes y no hubo exito  parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR","/ActividadM/");

Comment: Asi  no te va reconocer la ruta tienes que usar \  para poner la ruta